# Swift TableViewCell custome didSelect

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custome `TableViewCell`. When it is tapped, it should have a `cornerRadius` + a white background with `.alpha(0.7)`. Right now it is just the default `grey` which looks like this:

[image]

I tried setting `cornerRadius` and `backgroundColor` in `setSelected()` inside my `CustomCell` but that doesn't do anything.

***UPDATE***

I managed to get it done, almost:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    self.selectedBackgroundView = UIView()
    self.selectedBackgroundView?.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    self.selectedBackgroundView!.backgroundColor = selected ? .clear : .white
    self.selectedBackgroundView?.alpha = 0.5
}
```

this works fine, but the only thing it is not doing is applying the `alpha-value`. Any idea?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: @aheze wasnt quite sure what code would be helpful here. What do you need?

Comment: The code inside `setSelected`. Also, do you want to change the selected color, or the highlight color? Selected is when you press it, highlight is when you touch down.

Comment: @aheze isnt that the same? I mean if I touch down, I also press it, dont i?

Comment: Have you looked at the delegate methods `didSelectItemAt` and `didDeselectItemAt`?  What about the cell's own attribute `isSelected`?

Comment: @gmdev yes I tried it with `didSelectRowAt` but changing `contentView.backgroundColor` doenst do anything, still the default `grey`

Comment: Okay - if you could post the code that you have tried, like @aheze mentioned, that would be great.

Comment: updated the question. I managed to almost get it done how I want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually find it out by myself. Inside my `CustomCell`:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    self.selectedBackgroundView = UIView()
    self.selectedBackgroundView?.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    self.selectedBackgroundView!.backgroundColor = selected ? .clear : UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
}
```

[image]

Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you often need to call :

```
self.setNeedsLayout()
```

from within the setSelected function in order for alterations to the view of the cell to actually happen. Might be worth trying that.  Otherwise if you could post your setSelected function that would be very helpful in finding you a solution.